# Angular JS elements not appearing

Tags: angularjs

I wrote this code for an assignment but for some reason the Angular JS elements do not work. Instead nothing appears on the screen except for a small box containing the text 'Uthappizza'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
         content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController as detailCtrl">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-left media-middle">
                            <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                            <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                            <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                            <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);

        app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

            var dish={
                          name:'Uthapizza',
                          image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                          category: 'mains', 
                          label:'Hot',
                          price:'4.99',
                          description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }

                           ]
                    };

            this.dish = dish;

        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I suggest creating a JS Fiddle or something because it'd be difficult to debug without all of your CSS and JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html ng-controller you stated:

```
ng-controller="dishDetailController as detailCtrl"
```

so, you will have to use `detailCtrl.dish.<property>`

so the changes will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
         content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController as detailCtrl">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left media-middle">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h2 class="media-heading">{{detailCtrl.dish.name}}
                            <span class="label label-danger">{{detailCtrl.dish.label}}</span>
                            <span class="badge">{{detailCtrl.dish.price | currency}}</span></h2>
              <p>{{detailCtrl.dish.description}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('confusionApp', []);

      app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

        var dish = {
          name: 'Uthapizza',
          image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
          category: 'mains',
          label: 'Hot',
          price: '4.99',
          description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
          comments: [{
              rating: 5,
              comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
              author: "John Lemon",
              date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }, {
              rating: 4,
              comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
              author: "Paul McVites",
              date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }, {
              rating: 3,
              comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
              author: "Michael Jaikishan",
              date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }, {
              rating: 4,
              comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
              author: "Ringo Starry",
              date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }, {
              rating: 2,
              comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
              author: "25 Cent",
              date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }

          ]
        };

        this.dish = dish;

      });
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace dish with detailCtrl.dish in html. For example, instead of dish.name, use detailCtrl.dish.name in html